# How to Populate Pages file from Excel Worksheet using Applescript

Tags: macos, excel, applescript

I'm trying to populate a template from data in an Excel spreadsheet. This is my first foray into Applescript. My plan is to have unique text strings in the template (i.e. Value_1, Value_2, etc) then store each value in a variable and find and replace each variable with each string.

I would very much appreciate any help; here is where I'm at:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active workbook
        activate object worksheet "Page 2"
        copy range range "B7" of active sheet
        // Store as variable?
    end tell
end tell

tell application "Pages"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "v" using command down
        // Find and replace?
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: For the first part use `set a to string value of range "B7" of active sheet`. I don't think I understand exactly what you want to do with the value when inserting it into Numbers. Could you clarify that.

Comment: Thanks, Kassym. Works like a charm. What I'd like to do is, for example, "Find text 'B7_Value' in iWork Pages and replace with variable a".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do what you want :

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active workbook
        activate object worksheet "Sheet2"
        set B7_Value to string value of range "B7" of active sheet
    end tell
end tell

tell application "Pages"
    set my_text to first document's body text
    set temp to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of my_text & " | sed -e 's/B7_Value/" & B7_Value & "/g'"
    set first document's body text to temp
end tell
```

This script does not keep formatting. If you want to keep formatting perhaps something like this :

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active workbook
        activate object worksheet "Sheet2"
        set B7_Value to string value of range "B7" of active sheet
    end tell
end tell

tell application "Pages"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "f" using command down
        set the clipboard to "B7_Value"
        keystroke "v" using command down
        delay 0.1
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.1
        set the clipboard to B7_Value
        keystroke "v" using command down
        delay 0.1
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.1
        keystroke space
        delay 0.1
        key code 53 -- escape
    end tell
end tell
```

For this to work you will need to enable System Preferences --> Keyboard --> All controls.

Comment: Side note : This script does not keep the format of the text.

Comment: I'm going to have to play around with this and likely open a (few) more questions, but I assume it's possible to somehow maintain formatting? I'm going to need to replace values in a table.

Comment: If you want to retain the formatting the second part of the script is going to need to be re-written and use GUI scripting to control Pages' Find/Replace dialog. The current script copies everything as plain text, makes the substitution and puts it back.

Comment: Yes, my end goal is to replace a manual process of copy and pasting values into a template. Is that something you can help me with here or is it best to ask a new, more specific question?